# WordPress PHP Syntax error

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, bitnami

I got this error from my bitnami wordpress trying to load the theme am creating from scratch, here it is

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.7.3-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes......\header.php on line 36

Line 35 & 50

```
<div class="site-logo">
            <?php $site-title = get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/') ); ?>" rel="home">
                <div class="screen-reader-text">
                    <?php printf(esc_html__('Go to the home page of %1$s', 'popper' ); $site-title ); ?>
                </div>
                <?php 
                    if  (popper_custom_logo() ) {
                        echo popper_custom_logo();
                    } else { ?>
                        <div class="site-firstletter" aria-hidden="true">
                            <?php echo substr($site-title, 0, 1); ?>
                        </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Please what is wrong with this line of code?

Comment: You need to post your code snippet as nobody knows the full code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: Check again now please

Comment: `$site-title` that is interpreted by PHP as `site MINUS title`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a dash in your variable name. Per the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

So a solution is to change line 36 from:

```
<?php $site-title = get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
```

to, for example:

```
<?php $site_title = get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
```

Comment: I see, but removing the dash affect everything else because site-title is a class. What better way can I go around this?

Comment: Thanks. Proble solved